# Repo: Identify unused projects in manifest

Tags: repo

Is there a pattern for identifying projects that have been added in the past but which are no longer used in any build?

Comment: What do you mean by "build" ?

Comment: @KuanlinChen Anything that you're building.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `repo status --orphans` can do what you want.

```
$ repo help status
[...]
  -o, --orphans         include objects in working directory outside of repo
                        projects
```

Meaning projects that are not present in the manifest anymore.